# Cannot start a clean installation of MongoDB with a clean data directory UserNotFound

Tags: mongodb, datadirectory

TLDR: I am unable to start a clean installation of Mongo (from ZIP) with an empty data directory, because of a UserNotFound Error (the not found user is from the old installation).

In more detail: My initial Mongo database is working fine. For testing purpose I moved my current data directory and created a new one. So I stopped my running Windows Service with

```
mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db --remove
```

created a new data directory and tried to start a new MongoDB in noauth mode with

```
mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db --noauth
```

And here begins the trouble: MongoDB tries to connect with an user from my old database which is nowhere mentioned in the current settings. Here is the log

> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12508 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db 64-bit host=XXX
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.8-45-g4f1bd30460
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4f1bd3046036a8621c2ad5acde7cdf103a533226
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.323-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.327-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.327-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.327-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.327-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { security: { authorization: "disabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "C:\data\db" } }
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.330-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.330-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7379M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),cache_cursors=false,compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.569-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1540295147:568779][12508:140717431611728], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 2/4736
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.718-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1540295147:718169][12508:140717431611728], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 3
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:47.815-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1540295147:815426][12508:140717431611728], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 3
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.053-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1540295148:53068][12508:140717431611728], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.137-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify which IP
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
>
> 2018-10-23T04:45:48.138-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.471+0200 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'Das angegebene Objekt wurde nicht auf dem Computer gefunden.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.471+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.473+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.863+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57924 #1 (1 connection now open)
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.864+0200 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:57924 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_171-b11" }
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.865+0200 I ACCESS   [conn1] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for fritz1338 on admin from client 127.0.0.1:57924 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user fritz1338@admin
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:48.865+0200 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:57924 (0 connections now open)
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.366+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57925 #2 (1 connection now open)
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.367+0200 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:57925 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_171-b11" }
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.369+0200 I ACCESS   [conn2] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for fritz1338 on admin from client 127.0.0.1:57925 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user fritz1338@admin
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.370+0200 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:57925 (0 connections now open)
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.872+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57926 #3 (1 connection now open)
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.873+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:57926 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_171-b11" }
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.875+0200 I ACCESS   [conn3] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for fritz1338 on admin from client 127.0.0.1:57926 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user fritz1338@admin
>
> 2018-10-23T13:45:49.877+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:57926 (0 connections now open)

"fritz1338" is an user from my old db instance. If I move the old database directory to data\db everyting works fine again. But I cannot start a clean install from MongoDB.

What I have already tried:

- create a brand new data\db directory
- redownload MongoDB (ZIP File)
- searched the entire PC and registry for references to a mongo configuration file (even though mongo does not use an config file by default)
- removed the "mongo-java-driver" in my .m2 maven directory (evetn though it shouldn't been accessed)
- run the mongod repair option with

  mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db --repair

Can anyone tell me why aclean installation of MongoDB knows about an old username from another data directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
The log entries came from another application, which attempted to connect to the database.